# Questions on varnish

Tags: magento-1.8, varnish

i'm planning to apply varnish for my magento 1.81, but there are some questions

1) is varnish must run on port 80, and apache should set to another port?
2) what extension should be installed for the magento? Turpentine? is this good or are there any alternative are better?

3) any "updated" tutorial let me follow to install varnish? i searched the google, there are too many non-updated and scattered results.
4) how to handle ssl in varnish?

Answer (score 1):

First Apache has to be configured to answer to port 8080 instead to port 80 because Varnish is supposed to answer to port 80. This link shows you how to configure the ports: https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Getting_started.html#exercise-installation. Varnish is configured with an own language - Varnish Configuration Language (VCL). At first you install a "silly" VCL-file which passes all inquiries to Apache. Therefore the file /etc/varnish/default.vcl gets following content:

```
backend default {
   .host = "localhost";
   .port = "8080";
}
```

and has to be loaded new with:

```
service varnish reload
```

To install a Varnish module on Magento (e.g. Phoenix_PageCache) you have to follow these steps:

Adapt Magento-configuartion. Following configuration must be set to "no":

a) System->Configuration->(General)Web->Session validation settings->Use SID on frontend
b) System->Configuration->(General)Web->Browser Capabilities detection->Redirect to CMS-page if Cookies are Disabled

Establish the module-configuration. The following should be set to "yes", so the cache is deleated while changes:

a) System->Configuration->(Phoenix Media)PageCache powered by Varnish->Purge Category
b) System->Configuration->(Phoenix Media)PageCache powered by Varnish->Purge Product
c) System->Configuration->(Phoenix Media)PageCache powered by Varnish->Purge CMS Page

Replace the VCL-file: The module has its own VCL-filet, wich can be taken usually. Overwrite the earlier installed VCL with:
app/etc/default_3.0.vcl

Put cache-control headers for static contents. VCL orientates to the  HTTP-headers sent by Magento. For images-, CSS- and JavaScript-files you can set them with  .htaccess-files  in /skin, /js and /medi. These need to have following content:

`<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg|gif|jpeg|png)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 Header unset Last-Modified`

Here are some more details :http://www.code4business.de/magento-varnish/